# Download list of files and apply unique cleaning function to each then bind to single dataframe

Tags: r

I am extracting information from more than 30 pdfs that describe expenditures for the Army, Navy, Marines, and Air Force.

Each service formats its pdf differently, so I have written four separate cleaning functions that extract the data I need. (However, the pdfs sometime vary across years. So I may someday need to write specific cleaning functions for specific years.)

What technique should I use to download, apply the associated cleaning function, and rbind the many files?

Conceptually, my idea is to insert the relevant function in each row, and somehow use purrr to download, apply the associated function, then bind_row?

I have not seen this done before, but believe it must be a common practice. Examples/references/tutorials very welcome indeed!

```
#### Data (Example)#####

df <- expand.grid(
service = c("Army", "Navy", "Marines", "Air.Force"),
year = c(2010:2019)
) %>% tbl_df() %>% 
  mutate(my.hyperlink = str_c("http://", "_", service, "_", year, ".html"),
         my.cleaning.function = str_c(service, "cleaner",sep = "_" ))


# A tibble: 40 x 4
   service    year my.hyperlink                my.cleaning.function
   <fct>     <int> <chr>                       <chr>               
 1 Army       2010 http://_Army_2010.html      Army_cleaner        
 2 Navy       2010 http://_Navy_2010.html      Navy_cleaner        
 3 Marines    2010 http://_Marines_2010.html   Marines_cleaner     
 4 Air.Force  2010 http://_Air.Force_2010.html Air.Force_cleaner   
 5 Army       2011 http://_Army_2011.html      Army_cleaner        
 6 Navy       2011 http://_Navy_2011.html      Navy_cleaner        
 7 Marines    2011 http://_Marines_2011.html   Marines_cleaner     
 8 Air.Force  2011 http://_Air.Force_2011.html Air.Force_cleaner   
 9 Army       2012 http://_Army_2012.html      Army_cleaner        
10 Navy       2012 http://_Navy_2012.html      Navy_cleaner        
# ... with 30 more rows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example of how you can possibly do this. Please let me know if the example is not clear enough.

```r
library(tidyverse, quietly = TRUE)

df <- expand.grid(
  service = c("Army", "Navy", "Marines", "Air.Force"),
  year = c(2010:2019)
  ) %>% 
  tbl_df() %>% 
  mutate(my.hyperlink = str_c("http://", "_", service, "_", year, ".html"),
         my.cleaning.function = str_c(service, "cleaner",sep = "_" ))

# define two example functions
Army_cleaner <- function(txt) {
  tibble(
    my_text = str_to_lower(txt),
    my_num  = runif(4)
  )
}

Navy_cleaner <- function(txt) {
  tibble(
    my_text = str_to_upper(txt),
    my_num  = runif(4)
  )
}


# fiter the data.frame only for the functions that we have defined
# then run the example
df %>% 
  filter(my.cleaning.function %in% c("Army_cleaner", "Navy_cleaner")) %>% 
  mutate(my_data = map2(my.hyperlink, my.cleaning.function, ~ {
    FUN <- get(.y)
    FUN(.x)
    })) %>% 
  unnest()
#> # A tibble: 80 x 6
#>    service  year my.hyperlink      my.cleaning.funct… my_text       my_num
#>    <fct>   <int> <chr>             <chr>              <chr>          <dbl>
#>  1 Army     2010 http://_Army_201… Army_cleaner       http://_army… 0.478 
#>  2 Army     2010 http://_Army_201… Army_cleaner       http://_army… 0.386 
#>  3 Army     2010 http://_Army_201… Army_cleaner       http://_army… 0.225 
#>  4 Army     2010 http://_Army_201… Army_cleaner       http://_army… 0.421 
#>  5 Navy     2010 http://_Navy_201… Navy_cleaner       HTTP://_NAVY… 0.450 
#>  6 Navy     2010 http://_Navy_201… Navy_cleaner       HTTP://_NAVY… 0.515 
#>  7 Navy     2010 http://_Navy_201… Navy_cleaner       HTTP://_NAVY… 0.429 
#>  8 Navy     2010 http://_Navy_201… Navy_cleaner       HTTP://_NAVY… 0.0371
#>  9 Army     2011 http://_Army_201… Army_cleaner       http://_army… 0.433 
#> 10 Army     2011 http://_Army_201… Army_cleaner       http://_army… 0.354 
#> # ... with 70 more rows
```

Comment: `FUN <- get(.y)` copies the function from the global environment into the df row. `FUN(.x)` applies the function to the first argument (`.x`). If more arguments are required, use `pmap` and refer to arguments as `..1, ..2,`, etc. For example, `FUN <- get(..4) ` then `FUN(..1, ..2, ..3)`